# swift , load model function can't play animation but load function I can play

Tags: swift, arkit, usdz

```
 let me=try! ModelEntity.load(named: filename)
        print("count is \(me.availableAnimations.count)" )

        
        
        print("\(me.availableAnimations.count) model animation number model entity is ")
```

above is that I use load function, but availableAnimations.count is 1 so I can play

```
let me=try! ModelEntity.loadModel(named: filename)

        print("\(me.availableAnimations.count) model animation number model entity is")
```

but with loadModel function, availableAnimations.count is 0 so I can't play animation

is it possible for me to play animation with loadModel function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in loadModel method. Use load method instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).